# GUI, Process with Infinite Loop, and Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run two infinite loops simultaneously.  To my understanding, this is a good use for threading.

However, as soon as I assign one thread, it never executes the second. Allow me to show what I am doing.

```
import threading

def launch_gui() :
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )

def rospy_listen() :
    while(True) :
        print("Im listening")
```

The rospy_listen() is just a dummy function, my actual code has a working ROSPY implementation for a listener that is too hard to mull-down, but the bulk of the idea is that there is an always running loop inside of it.

However when I do the following in my main function...

```
rospy.init_node("setup_node", anonymous=True)
t1 = threading.Thread(target = launch_gui() )
t2 = threading.Thread(target = rospy_listen() )
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

It never even reaches t2 to turn the listener on.  How do I avoid this hang-up?

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrectly launched your threads. The line:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target = launch_gui() )
```

actually begins executing `launch_gui()` since you called it and *assigned* the result of it's execution as the target of your thread. Since it never returns, your main thread blocks instead of actually creating the thread and executing the target inside it.

Instead, you want to do this:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target = launch_gui )
```

which creates the thread and assigns it to execute `launch_gui` instead. The same should be done for the second thread.

```
t2 = threading.Thread(target = rospy_listen )
```

Comment: This is one of those "duh" moments.  Thank you. I will accept this answer once allowed.